# Switch case with case 2 equal to case 1 plus case 0

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I have a `switch statement` where when `$value == 2` the switch should post the same things of `case 0` and `case 1`.

```
switch($value){
    case 0:
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td align="right">';
        print "Sup:";
        print '</td>';
        print '<td>';
        print $sup;
        print '</td>';
        print '</tr>';
    break;  

    case 1:
        print '<tr>';
        print '<td align="right">';
        print "Inf:";
        print '</td>';
        print '<td>';
        print $inf;
        print '</td>';
        print '</tr>';
    break;

    case 2:
      //this case should post case 0 and case 1 together
    break;
}
```

Comment: Then putting your print statements into functions and using your cases to call those functions might be easier

Comment: When `$value == 2` it should do both case 1 and case 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not something like this:

```
function case0() {
   print '<tr>';
   print '<td align="right">';
   print "Sup:";
   print '</td>';
   print '<td>';
   print $sup;
   print '</td>';
   print '</tr>';
}

function case1() {
   print '<tr>';
   print '<td align="right">';
   print "Inf:";
   print '</td>';
   print '<td>';
   print $inf;
   print '</td>';
   print '</tr>';
}

switch($value) {
    case 0:
        case0();
    break;  

    case 1:
       case1();
    break;

    case 2:
      case0();
      case1(); 
    break;
}
```

Comment: not only solution but solution to switch/case. This way you can re-use the functions anytime you want and not hardcode for each case.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with a switch statement. You could use something like this:

```
if ($value == 0 || $value == 2) {
    // do "zero" stuff
}
if ($value == 1 || $value == 2) {
    // do "one" stuff
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
switch ($value) {
    case 2:
    case 0:
       // do "zero" stuff
       if ($value == 0) break;
    case 1:
       // do "one" stuff
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the HTML in variables and then use it in your `switch`.

```
$superiore = '<tr>
<td align="right">
Limite Superiore:
</td>
<td>'.
$entry['lim_sup'].'CHF/100LT
</td>
</tr>';

$inferiore = '<tr>
<td align="right">
Limite Inferiore:
</td>
<td>'.
$entry['lim_inf'].'CHF/100LT
</td>
</tr>';

switch($value){
    case 0:
        print $superiore;
    break;  

    case 1:
        print $inferiore;
    break;

    case 2:
        print $superiore;
        print $inferiore;
    break;
}
```